# Nativescript closeModal() not working

Tags: nativescript, showmodaldialog

Im trying to close a modal from my page. I used page.closeModal but its not working :(

Here is what I did to show the modal.

modal.js:

```
page.showModal("./views/samplemodal", "some custom context", function (ret) {
        console.log(ret)
    }, true);
```

Comment: Can you check, which version of {N} you are using, because closeModa() is first working in version 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Page.closeModal() must be called from a modal function.

```
<Button text="Cancel" tap="closeModal"/>

exports.closeModal = function() {
    page.closeModal();
};
```